# XMLHttpRequest with special characters in Safari Extension does not work

Tags: javascript, safari, xmlhttprequest, special-characters, safari-extension

Im trying to make an extension to Safari that authenticates with http://myphotodiary.com's API. And it works well, for all passwords that dont include special characters like:

> å,ä,ö and space

I have the following code working now:

```
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

var url = "https://api.myphotodiary.com/user_status.json?api_key=66217f993f25a8a05dd72970473aa2227450dcad";

var username = "iphone";
var password = "bdbiphone123";

var authy = Base64.encode(username+":"+password);

xmlHttp.open('GET', url, true);
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + authy);
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4){
    var data;
    eval("data="+xmlHttp.responseText);
    console.log(data);
}
};
xmlHttp.send(null);
```

This code works great for all passwords that dont include the special characters, but if i change the login info to

```
var username = "blpninja";
var password = "./ hejä";
```

it starts to fail.

This exact code works in Safari, but not when i put it in an extension.

I have also tried the xmlHttpRequest.open built in authentication

```
xmlHttp.open('GET', url, true, username, password);
```

with the same result.

This is my head of the global page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

</head>
```

I get the "Failed to load resource: cancelled" and these are the headers Safari is sending:

```
Authorization:Basic YmxwbmluamE6Li8gaGVqw6Q=
Content-Type:text/xml; charset=utf-8
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_4; sv-se) AppleWebKit/533.16 (KHTML, like Gecko)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure and no time to delve into it, but maybe encoding the strings will help?

```
var username = encodeURIComponent("blpninja"), //=> sends: blpninja
    password = encodeURIComponent("./ hejä");  //=> sends: .%2F%20hej%C3%A4
```

on the server side it may have do be decoded (`decodeURIComponent`)

Comment: I just solved the problem by encodeURIComponent(password) and then using the build-in auth function in xmlHttpRequest.open()

Thx!

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance. Kladdkaka would be nice ;-)